# 5G strandard pilot allocation, channel estimation method

Tags: matlab, ofdm, channel-estimation

I'm trying to create an OFDM simulation, but I don't know the 5G standard pilot allocation estimation method.

Is this simulation good?
One transmission unit has $64$ subcarriers and $14$ OFDM symbols. The position of the pilot signal is the $2$nd, $4$th,…, $62$nd, $64$th subcarrier of the $3$rd, $12$th OFDM symbol.

For channel estimation, $h_{p} = \frac{y_{p}}{x_{p}}$ is performed at the pilot signal position, and linear interpolation is performed on the time and frequency axes. The frequency selectivity channel is constant during $1$ OFDM symbols.

I used this site as a reference to determine the location of the pilot signal: https://jp.mathworks.com/help/5g/ug/deep-learning-data-synthesis-for-5g-channel-estimation.html

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, what is the question?

Comment: Hi.I want to understand some pilot patterns ,and how to use depending on the situation

Comment: For pilot pattern, ok for subcarrier mapping but for symbols, the closet to what you have described is 3rd, 8th, and 12th symbols. For channel estimation, yes you can do least square and linear interpolation. Note that there are other interpolation types and other estimation methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pilot symbols are laid out in different ways depending on what part of the signal you have. For example, the possible pilot symbol allocations for the PDSCH part of the waveform in very flexible. They may have different pattern in frequency domain, time domain, and may have different weightings. This page illustrates: https://www.sharetechnote.com/html/5G/5G_PDSCH_DMRS.html.

You asked, is your simulation good? Seems ok to me, I don't think it exactly matches any of the valid 5G pilot allocations though, so if that is what you were after then I'd suggest looking into the link I provided (there is even example MATLAB code snippets if that is what you are using).